REACT.JS: Uncaught TypeError: "function" is not a function
Problema ao passar uma função como parâmetro entre componentes no React
Estou enfrentando um problema ao passar uma função como parâmetro de um componente pai para um componente filho no React. No arquivo principal, tenho o seguinte código:
export default function App() {
  const [filterParams, setFilterParams] = useState({});

  const onFilterClick = (municipio, estado, estabelecimento) => {
    setFilterParams({
      municipio_filtrado: municipio,
      estado_filtrado: estado,
      estabelecimento_filtrado: estabelecimento,
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Title />
      <Filter onFilter={onFilterClick} />
    </>
  );
}

No componente filho (Filter), tento chamar a função onFilterClick quando clico em um botão:
export default function Filter({ onFilter }) {
  const handleFilterClick = () => {
    console.log(estado, municipio, estabelecimento);
    let estado_split = (estado || "").split(" ");
    let municipio_split = (municipio || "").split(" ");
    let estabelecimento_split = (estabelecimento || "").split(" ");

    onFilter(municipio_split[0], estado_split[0], estabelecimento_split[0]);
  };

  return (
    <Button
      variant="contained"
      sx={{ m: 2, width: 100, height: 40 }}
      size="small"
      onClick={handleFilterClick}
    >
      Filtrar
    </Button>
  );
}```

Ao clicar no botão, recebo o seguinte erro no console:

Uncaught TypeError: onFilter is not a function
    at handleFilterClick


No componente Filter não vi a declaração das variáveis de estado, municio e estabelecimento. Garantir q estas variaveis estejam inicializadas no componente filho pode ajudar.
Mas caso ainda estiver enfrentando problemas com a chamada de onFilterClick, deixe com comentário pra q possamos te ajudar :)
